# How to find the longest path in binary search tree using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

Im trying to figure out how to find the longest path in a binary search tree (not really experienced with bst and recursion) and  found a solution which i simply dont understand.

```
const height = (node) => {
  if(!node) return 0;
  var leftHeight = height(node.left);
  var rightHeight = height(node.right);
  return Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
}
height(node)
```

1. Where is the counter ? As I see it, in leftHeight and rightHeight would be stored the last value. How is it possible that without counting each value, it does count?
2. Where do I actually return the value? I return the final result --> Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight) but where do I add, save, return the values in each recursive call ?

An explanation would be truly amazing! THANKS!

Comment: Can you, please, give us a 'node' so we can figure out the data you working on ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically at some point your callstack will be the longest path.

so lets take this tree:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
   / \
  D   E
```

here as JS:

```
{
    name: 'A'
    left: {
        name: 'B',
        left: null,
        right: null,
    }
    right: {
        name: 'C',
        left: {
            name: 'D',
            left: null,
            right: null,
        },
        right: {
            name: 'E',
            left: null,
            right: null,
        }
    }
}
```

Then you do `node(nodeA)`. From now on I will use `nodeX` to reference to the object for the node `X`.

then `height(node.left);` will be executed, and because `node.left` is `nodeB` this is basically `height(nodeB)`. So your callstack is then this:

```
height(nodeA)
height(nodeB)
```

now `height(node.left);` is executed (node is now `nodeB`). and because `left` of `nodeB` is `null` this is essentially `height(nodeB)`. Your callstack is then this:

```
height(nodeA)
height(nodeB)
height(null)
```

now the line `if(!node) return 0;` will immediately return from the function, because `node` is `null` and so `!node` is `true`. The return will be `0` as specified.

The callstack is now again this (the last stack element was removed):

```
height(nodeA)
height(nodeB)
```

and the value `leftHeight` will now be 0 (because thats what was just returned).
The line `var rightHeight = height(node.right);` will essentially do the same, because `node.right` is also null. So `Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight)` is essentially `Math.max(0, 0)` and so 0. This plus `1` is one. This will be returned. The callstack is now like this:

```
height(nodeA)
```

and `leftHeight` has the value `1` which is correct.

The same happens now for the right side, so for `C`. Here however `node.left` will not be null but `nodeD`, and so another stack frame will be build:

```
height(nodeA)
height(nodeC)
height(nodeD)
```

here `nodeD` has null for left and right and will return 1, identical to `nodeB`. The same happens to `nodeE`. Then `nodeC` then will have `leftHeight` to be `1` and `rightHeight` to be one. This plus 1 is 2, so `height(nodeC)` will return `2`.

Then the `height(nodeA)` will have `leftHeight` to be `1` and `rightHeight` to be `2`. So `Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;` is 3 and the correct result.

---

Basically your code *is* counting, and the `+1` *is* the counting. The starting point for the counts is always the `return 0`.